# Add shortcode and div into PHP output to new shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

**This is the current HTML but I'd like to create a shortcode to display it all...**

```
<div class="widget" sp-sku="sku-value-goes-here"></div>
```

**I setup a shortcode that get the SKU**

```
function wc_get_product_sku() { 
    global $product;
    echo $product->get_sku();
add_shortcode('product_sku', 'wc_get_product_sku');
```

**But I'd like a new shortcode to output the entire div with the shortcode or sku in the div class.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and give the [WordPress Shortcode](https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/) documentation a glance. The shortcode you have *now* is improper. WordPress Shortcodes are supposed to `return` a value, not `echo` or otherwise output it. If you see `echo` statements in a shortcode function, generally they have [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) enabled, and then return the final value. (you also have a syntax error)

The following would be the proper way to implement your current function:

```
add_shortcode('product_sku', 'wc_get_product_sku'); 
function wc_get_product_sku() { 
    global $product;

    return $product->get_sku();
}
```

If you want to output the HTML, just include that in the return value. If you want another function:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_sku_div', 'wc_product_sku_div'); 
function wc_product_sku_div() { 
    global $product;

    return sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $product->get_sku() );
}
```

Alternatively, you could add them to the same function and use *shortcode attributes* to determine whether to output the whole HTML or just the SKU, something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_get_product_sku', 'wc_get_product_sku_function'); 
function wc_get_product_sku_function( $atts ) { 
    global $product;
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'wrap' => false,
    ), $atts, 'wc_get_product_sku' ) );

    return ($wrap == true) ? sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $sku ) : $sku;
}
```

This would like you use `[wc_get_product_sku]` or `[wc_get_product_sku wrap="false"]` to get just the sku, and `[wc_get_product_sku wrap="true"]` to get the whole HTML.

Edit: to check the sku, just wrap the return statement in an if/else:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_sku_div', 'wc_product_sku_div'); 
function wc_product_sku_div() { 
    global $product;

    if( $product && !empty( $product->get_sku() ) ){
        return sprintf( '<div class="widget" sp-sku="%s"></div>', $product->get_sku() );    
    } else {
        return '<div>NO SKU FOUND</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The middle one worked perfectly. Would you know how to use the middle code but add an if/else. If there is a sku then show the div. If not then show and alternative div.

Comment: I added an edit. I'm not entirely sure what `WC_Product::get_sku()` returns when there is no SKU, so I took a stab and went with `!empty($product->get_sku())`, but you can change that if it's something else - the if/else structure should remain the same

Comment: I have another side question. It appears that woocommerce uses the Sku Meta Data to change images and the SKU on display. Using the above code the sku updates on the page but the sku does not update inside the div.